# Como realizar UPDATE com PDO no PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Então pessoal, eu queria resgatar os dados para editar no `update.php`, mas to meio perdido aqui, tem como dar uma força?

```
   <div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Produtos</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Opções</td>
        </tr>
            <?php foreach ($resultado as $key) :?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key->nome;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->marca;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->modelo;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->quantidade;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->estado;?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="mysql/update.php?id=<?php echo $key->id; ?>">Alterar</a>
                <a href="mysql/delete.php?id=<?php echo $key->id; ?>">/Deletar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
</div>
```

- update.php

  ```
      <?php 
  try{
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE FROM estoqueprodutos . produtos WHERE id = $id");
      $sql->execute();
      var_dump($id);

      echo $sql->rowCount();

  }catch (PDOException $e){
      echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();

  }    ?>
  ```

  **EDITADO**

Pessoal estou com um problema eu criei esse código para ficar mais enxuto mas não esta executando e não esta me dando nenhum erro vocês poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

```
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    try {
        $sql = "update produtos set nome = ?, marca = ?, modelo = ?, quantidade = ?, estado = ? where id = ?";

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $statement->bindParam(1, $_POST['nome']);
        $statement->bindParam(2, $_POST['marca']);
        $statement->bindParam(3, $_POST['modelo']);
        $statement->bindParam(4, $_POST['quant']);
        $statement->bindParam(5, $_POST['estado']);
        $statement->bindParam(6, $_POST['id']);

        $statement->execute();


        var_dump($statement);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "Desculpe-nos, mas não foi possível alterar este produto. Entre em contato com o suporte!";
}
```

?>

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? De PHP e PDO não sei o que você está perguntando, mas seria bom ao menos ler o manual do SQL para ver a sintaxe do UPDATE.

Comment: É quase isso, só falta criar os inputs com os valores do banco e usa prepared statements de forma correta.

Comment: eu quero resgatar os dados da tabela pelo id e editar na minha update.php mas estou perdido quanto a isso.

Comment: @felipemarques seria legal você [edit] a pergunta e colocar essa informação, e todos os detalhes possíveis da dificuldade que está tendo, senão vira um jogo de adivinhação. Sugestão de leitura: [ask]

Comment: Faça um select, especificando o `id`, e executa o `update` quando o formulário for submetido.

Comment: @felipemarques se for uma dúvida diferente, faça uma nova pergunta separada desta. Se não está dando erro nenhum, pode ser que o ID esteja indo vazio, então ele nem tenta fazer o update; Precisa checar o FORM que manda estes dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lógica para realizar o update é a seguinte, no seu arquivo `update.php` ele não ira executar um `UPDATE tabela SET campo = valor`.

`update.php` em você precisa fazer uma consulta no banco de dados através do id recebido pelo get, com as informações em mãos crie o form html e preencha o atributo `value` com valor do banco de dados algo como:

```
<?php
//linhas omitidas ...
$sql->execute();
$registro = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<form method="post" action="gravar.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<php echo $registro['id']; ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="nome" value="<php echo $registro['nome']; ?>" />
```

No arquivo `grava.php` será gravado um novo registro ou atualizado. Mas como saber qual operação realizar?

Isso pode ser feito através da verificação do valor de `id`(ver campos do form).

gravar.php

```
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST['id']){
      //realizar um update
  }else{
      //Não existe um id, logo é um registro novo, insert nele!
  }
```

Comment: cara desculpa a pergunta mas não consegui entender oque ficaria nas linha omitidas no update.php

Comment: @felipemarques quer dizer que não coloquei todo o código, só coloquei as linhas que mudam.

Comment: entendi , desculpa mesmo pela pergunta, to me sentindo um inutil aqui.

Comment: @felipemarques, nem esquente com isso, o melhor mesmo é não ficar com dúvidas.

Comment: Felipemarques é sempre bom perguntar, e não ficar em dúvida como o @rray disse. Mas procure sempre elaborar as questões de forma a ficarem com o máximo de detalhes relevantes possíveis, pois aumenta a chance de as respostas serem completas e focadas no seu problema real. E lembre-se que você pode fazer várias perguntas, à medida que for tendo dificuldades em outras partes do processo. Entenda que nossos comentários são sempre dicas para ajudar a melhorar, e não significa que não gostamos da pergunta.

Comment: entendi, obrigado pela dica.